# How to get the unit test results in variables in Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in Azure DevOps and I'm using the .NET Core task for applying unit testing.

I need to get the result of the unit tests in variables. For example, if there are 10 tests cases and two failed, I need to get something like:

```
failedTestCases = 2
succeededTestCases = 8
```

This is because I need those values in the next tasks. Is there a way to do that?

To be clear, I don't need to publish the results, they are already being published, I need to get those values in execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but in my opinion you need to use REST API. Below you will find part of build definition. There are three steps:

- test app
- get test details
- display test details

For you very important part is to figure out which log id you have for your test. Bascially if your test task is on 5th position on this list (including `Initialize job`):

[image]

You need to add 3 and you have your logId. In my case this is 8.

```yaml
variables:
  devopsAccount : 'thecodemanual'
  projectName : 'DevOps Manual'
  logId: "8"
```

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'dotnet-core-on-windows/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- RunConfiguration.DisableAppDomain=true'
    workingDirectory: $(rootDirectory)

- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: always()
  name: testDetails
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        # Encode the Personal Access Token (PAT)
        $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$(System.AccessToken)")) }

        # Get a list of releases
        $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$(devopsAccount)/$(projectName)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/logs/$(logId)?api-version=5.1"

        Write-Host $uri

        # Invoke the REST call
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader

        Write-Host $result

        $lines = $result.Split([Environment]::NewLine)

        $passed = 0;
        $failed = 0;

        foreach($line in $lines) {
            if ($line -match "Passed:.(\d+)") { 
              $passed = $matches[1]
            }

            if ($line -match "Failed:.(\d+)") { 
              $failed = $matches[1]
            }
        }

        echo $passed
        echo $failed

        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=passed]$passed"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=failed]$failed"

- script: |
    echo $(passed)
    echo $(failed)
  condition: always()
```

And for this I got:

[image]

So it means we have number of passed and failed tests in variables ready to use.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof Madej, thanks for your answer, i really appretiate it and I can use it.
I made some tests and the solution kind of worked. I need to make some adjustments to it.

But I don't completely like the part where I need to "force" the task's position number, because it can easily change if you move the task or add other tasks to the pipeline.
Do you know if there is a way to get that number from a variable.

Comment: I checked the problems I was having with your solution and it was caused because my log are in Spanish, so I was looking for "Correcto" instead of "Passed" and "Incorrecto" instead of "Failed", so both of that words contains "correcto" and I was getting the failed tests in both variables. I just fixed it and it worked perfectly. Still, I'm a little worried about the "forced" task's position number. I have been searching in the internet and couldn't find anything to get that value dinamically.

Comment: It is somehow possible. For instance you can use REST API to get Id based on the name. However, if you change a name, the whole pipeline fail.

Comment: That's better, I think. I was checking the REST API documentation and I can't find any endpoint to get the task by name, that was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for asking you again, but, do you know which is the endpoint by name?

Comment: Please use this [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it!